# Asp.net Identity DbContext / Repository Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, repository-pattern

I am using Asp.Net identity within my MVC app. I can see that this has it's own ApplicationDbContext - albeit it is connected to the same SQL db as my own DbContext I am using elsewhere.

So I am trying to access some of my own data via my own code within the AccountController - it does not seem to work I presume because of some confusion over which DBContext it thinks is active?

My Code :

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private PostageManager postmgr;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, PostageManager _postmgr)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        postmgr = _postmgr;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        //create select list items for countries drop down
        List<SelectListItem> countries;
        countries = postmgr.GetCountries().Select(item => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = item.Country,
            Text = item.Country
        }).ToList();
        countries.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = string.Empty, Text = "Select delivery country or region...", Selected = true });
        RegisterViewModel mode = new RegisterViewModel
        {
            Countries = countries
        };
        return View();
    }

}
```

}

PostageManager is just a class that sits over my DAL to fetch some data (which uses repository pattern) - I'm using just a kind of pass through method to grab a list of countries, and using it in exactly the same way I have in other controllers which works fine. Underneath that class is my repository code that is linked to my default connection string (DBContext). It's balking at the following line with a null reference exception, I think postmgr is null :

```
countries = postmgr.GetCountries().Select(item => new SelectListItem
```

In reverse to get access to the identity data within my own controllers I have done the following :

```
public BasketController(BasketManager _mgr, PostageManager _postmgr, ProductManager _prodmgr)
    {
        mgr = _mgr;
        postmgr = _postmgr;
        prodmgr = _prodmgr;
        shopper = Cart.GetShopperId();
        this.applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(this.applicationDbContext));
    }

    protected ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext { get; set; }
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager { get; set; }
```

Which as far as I understand it points the identity code to use the right DbContext - I looked at doing this in reverse in my AccountController but can't fathom it out.

I basically just want to be able to use my own code that grabs my own data from within the Identity controllers to help pass extra data etc through to the views.

Comment: It should not create a conflict that you have different DbContexts. I usually set up two different DbContexts towards the same SQL server when I do the "standard" CQRS pattern, one DbContext for writes, the other for reads (with change tracking disabled to improve read speed). In a previous question here, I got a confirmation that even the internal static EF objects, such as connection pools, are unique to each DbContext. Can't help you with the entire question though, looking forward to see the answer to this one.

Comment: It may well just be my stupidity that's making it not work of course! This is the first time I've used the Asp.Net Identity / MVC setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out - added the following to my NinjectControllerFactory :

```
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication); //.InRequestScope();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().ToSelf();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>().To<RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>>();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>().ToSelf();
```

And changed my constructor to :

```
 public AccountController(PostageManager _postmgr)
    {
        postmgr = _postmgr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but most probably postmgr field is not initialized from constructor and that is why you have this error.
Explanation:

By default Asp will try to create controller instance by constructor without parameters. If Asp can't find constructor without parameters it will try to call constructor with parameters, but to make it possible you have to configure IoC in your app. As your controler has constructor without parameters it will be selected by Asp. So all 3 fields are empty.

But in properties SignInManager and UserManager you try to take value from field or from OwinContext. As field is empty your code will take value from OwinContext. OwinContext is quite complex and smart tool that create its context automatically based on configuration provided in Startup.Auth.cs file or any other file under App_Start folder.

Comment: OK I can see that it is using the constructor without parameters so that is why my PostageManager is null. I can't see how to pass in my PostageManager - if I add it to the currently empty constructor I get an error from Ninject as below : Additional information: Error activating IUserStore{ApplicationUser}

I can't see how I need to bind / map the Identity code to overcome this?